# Ex 3.3.5 ( part 2 ) from Tao analysis book

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ be functions. Given that their composition $g\circ f:X\to Z$ is surjective, prove that $g$ must be surjective while $f$ need not to be.

How do I proof that $f$ need not to be surjective? Without giving a counter example. Is there a constructive proof?

My attempt is that I let the image of $f = Y' \subset Y$, so $f$ is not a surjection,and let $g(Y')=Z$.
Is it true?

Comment: Do give a counter-example!

Comment: Actually I'm trying to give a constructive proof.

Comment: There's nothing non-constructive about a simple counter-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $z\in Z$, then by assumption there exists $x\in X$ such that $(gf)(x) = z$ i.e $g(f(x)) = z$. As $z$ is arbitrary, what do you conclude about $g$?

To show $f$ need not be surjective it suffices to exhibit one example of functions $f,g$ such that $gf$ is surjective and $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: Is my attempt true that is to show that $g(Y')=Z$ where $Y'$ is the image of $f$.

Comment: @KareemTaha That's the idea, yes, but you have to justify that situation is possible by giving a specific example.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $f$ need not be surjective you only have to give an example. Take $X=Y=\mathbb R$ and $Z=\{0\}$. Let $f(x)=g(x)=0$ for all $x$ then $g(f(x))$ is surjective but $f$ is not.

Your argument does not answer the question. You have to give a specific example.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample: let $X=Y = \mathbb R, Z=[0, \infty), f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x.$

Show that $f,g$ and $ g \circ f$ have the desired properties.

Answer (score 0):

It is possibe that g be surjective but not injective.

In which case:

If $g$ is surjective then for every $z\in Z$ there exists AT LEAST one $y \in Y$ such that $g(y)= z$

If $g$ is NOT injective then there exist $y_1,y_2\in Y$ such that $g(y_1) = g(y_2)$

There is no need for there to be an $x\in X$ such that $f(x) = y_1$ so long as there is an $x$ such that $f(x) = y_2$

For example:

let $X = Y = Z = [-1,1]$

$f(x) = x^2\\
g(y)=|2y| - 1$

$g\circ f(x)$ is surjective, $f(x)$ is not surjective, $g(x)$ is surjective.

Comment: Then is it true that $g$ maps only the image of $f$ which is subset of $Y$.

Comment: $g$ maps all of $Y$ onto $Z.$ It also happens to map a subset of $Y$ onto $Z.$

Comment: If $g$ maps all of $Y$ how do I prove that $f$ is not surjective when $g$ is injective.

Comment: Thanks I see now that it is sufficient to prove in general that g is not surjective by considering the case g is not injective.